# Undefined identifier fwritefln

Tags: d

I'm learning D and having some difficulty with a standard library import.

```
import std.stdio;

void main(string[] args) {
    fwritefln(stderr, "foo");
}
```

Compiling with "gdc foo.d" produces the following error

```
foo.d:4: error: undefined identifier fwritefln, did you mean template writefln(T...)(T args)?
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Most library imports I've tried, I've had no difficulty with, but for some reason, this "fwritefln" is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
stderr.writefln(...);
```

This is the D's equivalent to C's `fprintf(stderr, ...)`

Every OutputStream has set of writef* methods that can be used to send formatted strings. More about it here: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stream.html#.OutputStream.writef

Comment: It looks like I've been looking at some faulty documentation.  Since I'm new to the language, I guess I'm not familiar with some of the incompatible implementations.  Maybe D version, maybe stdlib? http://www.docwiki.net/view.php?pageid=144

Comment: It's the documentation to D1 only. Current D version is D2. A a lot of stuff gets changed since. Check out new D web site: http://dlang.org/ and documentation to new `std.stdio`: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html#.File.writefln

Answer (score 1):

Well like the error already suggests change "fwritefln" to "writefln".

It seems to be a misspelling error on your side.

There is no fwritefln in the std.stdio module:
http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html

Comment: fwritefln is not the same as writefln.  The first one writes to an arbitrary stream, while the second one writes only to STDOUT.